# File is not sort after sort

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, uniq

I have a problem with sorting my file. My file look like this

`geom-10-11.com 1
geom-1-10.com 9
geom-1-11.com 10
geom-1-2.com 1
geom-1-3.com 2
geom-1-4.com 3
geom-1-5.com 4
geom-1-6.com 5
geom-1-7.com 6
geom-1-8.com 7
geom-1-9.com 8
geom-2-10.com 8
geom-2-11.com 9
geom-2-3.com 1
geom-2-4.com 2
geom-2-5.com 3
geom-2-6.com 4
geom-2-7.com 5
geom-2-8.com 6
geom-2-9.com 7
geom-3-10.com 7
geom-3-11.com 8
geom-3-4.com 1
geom-3-5.com 2
geom-3-6.com 3
geom-3-7.com 4
geom-3-8.com 5
geom-3-9.com 6
geom-4-10.com 6
geom-4-11.com 7
geom-4-5.com 1
geom-4-6.com 2
geom-4-7.com 3
geom-4-8.com 4
geom-4-9.com 5
geom-5-10.com 5
geom-5-11.com 6
geom-5-6.com 1
geom-5-7.com 2
geom-5-8.com 3
geom-5-9.com 4
geom-6-10.com 4
geom-6-11.com 5
geom-6-7.com 1
geom-6-8.com 2
geom-6-9.com 3
geom-7-10.com 3
geom-7-11.com 4
geom-7-8.com 1
geom-7-9.com 2
geom-8-10.com 2
geom-8-11.com 3
geom-8-9.com 1
geom-9-10.com 1
geom-9-11.com 2`

So I used `sort -k1.6 -k2 -n` and I got

`geom-1-2.com 1
geom-1-3.com 2
geom-1-4.com 3
geom-1-5.com 4
geom-1-6.com 5
geom-1-7.com 6
geom-1-8.com 7
geom-1-9.com 8
geom-1-10.com 9
geom-1-11.com 10
geom-2-3.com 1
geom-2-4.com 2
geom-2-5.com 3
geom-2-6.com 4
geom-2-7.com 5
geom-2-8.com 6
geom-2-9.com 7
geom-2-10.com 8
geom-2-11.com 9
geom-3-4.com 1
geom-3-5.com 2
geom-3-6.com 3
geom-3-7.com 4
geom-3-8.com 5
geom-3-9.com 6
geom-3-10.com 7
geom-3-11.com 8
geom-4-5.com 1
geom-4-6.com 2
geom-4-7.com 3
geom-4-8.com 4
geom-4-9.com 5
geom-4-10.com 6
geom-4-11.com 7
geom-5-6.com 1
geom-5-7.com 2
geom-5-8.com 3
geom-5-9.com 4
geom-5-10.com 5
geom-5-11.com 6
geom-6-7.com 1
geom-6-8.com 2
geom-6-9.com 3
geom-6-10.com 4
geom-6-11.com 5
geom-7-8.com 1
geom-7-9.com 2
geom-7-10.com 3
geom-7-11.com 4
geom-8-9.com 1
geom-8-10.com 2
geom-8-11.com 3
geom-9-10.com 1
geom-9-11.com 2
geom-10-11.com 1`

**But when I tried use** `uniq -f1` **or** `sort -k1.6 -k2 -n -u` **I got same long sorted output. So I used** 
`sort -k1.6 -k2 -n -c`
**and get message that this file is disordered**

(`sort: glist2:2: disorder: geom-1-2.com 1`).

I tried use just `sort -k2 -n -u` but got

`geom-10-11.com 1
geom-1-3.com 2
geom-1-4.com 3
geom-1-5.com 4
geom-1-6.com 5
geom-1-7.com 6
geom-1-8.com 7
geom-1-9.com 8
geom-1-10.com 9
geom-1-11.com 10`

That is not what I need, I need to have

`geom-1-2.com 1
geom-1-3.com 2
geom-1-4.com 3
geom-1-5.com 4
geom-1-6.com 5
geom-1-7.com 6
geom-1-8.com 7
geom-1-9.com 8
geom-1-10.com 9
geom-1-11.com 10`

So I need to have at begening geom-1-X and not geom-10-X. It would be great use juste uniq because I have more bigger files with more geometries (about thousands of lines) but with same structure. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Your input file doesn't match the given result examples. E.g. the entry `geom-1-11-14.com 10 3` is not present in any of the example. Is it on purpose? If yes, please explain. If not, please update your examples.

Comment: @oliv Thank you for your comment. I edit my post and put here less complex example of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
grep -E '^geom-1-' file | sort -k1.8n
```

`grep` is filtering the lines you want. `sort` is sorting numerically the first field starting at the 8th character.